# If I modify a primary key's type, will auto_increment remain intact?

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose that I have a table created like:

```
create table my_rows(
    id int primary key auto_increment;
    /*...*/
)
```

and I want to earn some unused space and would like to convert it into a `smallint`, then, I think about modifying it like

```
alter table my_rows
modify column id unsigned int primary key auto_increment;
```

Let's assume that there were some ids, up to a certain level, let's say, 257. Is it true that after such a change the value of the id of the next row will be exactly 258, that is, the auto_increment counter will be intact? If not, how should I remedy this?

Comment: Did you think of just writing a test of this on a seperate table

Comment: @RiggsFolly my plan was to finish something and after that, if no feasible answer was provided, to conduct a few experiments and answer my question myself. I believe that such a question definitely has a place under the sun, it's not a gimme tha code type of question and I did not find anything on the Internet which would help. So, my idea was to create a question which is up for grabs and if nobody grabs it, I will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works without issues you can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85a2d1/3/0

See how you can insert rows with setting the `id` by hand or letting the `auto_increment` do it's magic

```
create table my_rows(
    id int NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50)
);

insert into my_rows(name) values ('One'), ('Two');
insert into my_rows(id, name) values (3, 'Three');

ALTER TABLE my_rows MODIFY id smallint NOT NULL auto_increment;

insert into my_rows(name) values ('Four');
insert into my_rows(id, name) values (5, 'Five');


select * from my_rows;
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_rows;

/* output looks like: */
id  name
1   One
2   Two
3   Three
4   Four
5   Five
```

**Note:** Auto_increment does not fill "empty" spots. So if you set `id`s by hand and leave some empty spots in between and then continue with `auto_increment` the "empty spots" will not be filled. So here `6` and `7` will be missing

```
create table my_rows(
    id int NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50)
);

insert into my_rows(name) values ('One'), ('Two');
insert into my_rows(id, name) values (3, 'Three');

ALTER TABLE my_rows MODIFY id smallint NOT NULL auto_increment;

insert into my_rows(name) values ('Four');
insert into my_rows(id, name) values (5, 'Five');

insert into my_rows(id, name) values (8, 'Eight');
insert into my_rows(name) values ('Nine');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b993d/1/0

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder whether we can only know this by testing and hoping that there are no edge cases or is this a known feature of auto_increment. (I mean the feature that it keeps its position after altering)